# How can I build a "nested for-loop generator"?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

#### Question

Assume I have a list like `['key1','key2', ... ,'keyN']` and a function `f()`.
`f()` follows the signature `bar = f(foo,key)`, where `foo` & `bar` is an arbitrary object that is iterable.

How do I generate a nested for loop following the structure below (assuming arbitrary keys and amount of keys):

```
for x1 in f(root,key1):
    for x2 in f(x1,key2):
        ...
            for xN in f(xN-1,keyN):
                # some code here
                pass
```

#### Example

I stumbled up this when I tried to elegantly crawl thru a xml file.
Assume you have an xml file with a structure like this:

```xml
<xml>
 <records>
   <record>
     <contributors>
       <authors>
         <author>A</author>
         <author>B</author>
         <author>C</author>
       </authors>
     </contributors>
     ...
   </record>
   ...
  </records>
  ...
</xml>
```

And you would like to extract the authors of all the records in the xml file and you know "where they are" - i.g. you have the list `[records,record,contributors,authors]`
How do you write a function that extracts this kind of information for an arbitrary list of keys

Comment: Are you familiar with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and possibly [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)?

Comment: sounds like maybe you want a recursive function?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the list of keys. Does `f` return a nested `dict`, so that `f()['key1']['key2']...['keyN']` makes sense?

Comment: @Brian Yes, but this only produces a list of objects to iter thru - if I understood you correctly. The difficulty (for me) is to apply a function to this object and use its output as the input of the next loop

Comment: @chepner No. It does return an arbitrary iterable object. Hence ```f()['key1']['key2']...['keyN']``` would not be valid.

Comment: Then what *is* valid? Where do `'key1'` et al. come into the picture?

Comment: @chepner You are right, i forget them. See edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something recursive like

```
def with_keys(node, keys):
    if not keys:
        #some code

    current_key = keys[0]
    next_keys = keys[1:]

    for x in f(node, current_key):
        with_keys(x, next_keys)


with_keys(root, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
```

This is just a rough sketch, as it doesn't take into consideration any state changes made by `# some code` that may need to persist across iterations.

Comment: for x in f(node, current_key): if len(next_keys) == 0: pass; else: with_keys(x, next_keys)